# Does decline have plural form?

Tags: countability

Does decline have **plural form**?

Is it correct to say there were **declines** in the amount of fish and beef consumed in the UK?

One of my students asked me this question in an IELTS Writing class, but I was not uncertain about it.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t see anything in the dictionary indicating “decline” can’t be plural.

> there were **declines** in the **amount** of fish and beef consumed in the UK

As written, this indicates multiple separate declines in the total amount of both fish and beef consumed. I doubt that is what was meant.

> there were **declines** in the **amounts** of fish and beef consumed in the UK

By making “amounts” also plural, this leads to a more likely meaning there was a decline in fish and a decline in beef.

> there was a **decline** in the **amount** of fish and beef consumed in the UK

By making both singular, we have one decline in both fish and beef, with the implication of a common cause. It would most likely be interpreted as both declining, but technically it means only the total declined.

> there were **declines** in the **amount** of fish and in the **amount** of beef consumed in the UK

This clearly says that each declined separately. You could also use “decline” here, though.

> UK consumption of fish and beef declined

This is what I would probably say, but that’s just a matter of style.

Comment: Your explanation is very clear and helpful! Thank you!